# User can't see latest revision updates

Tags: word

I have a user that updated a word document saved and checked in. Versioning is turned on with Major and Minor revisions. The latest version is 8.0 Here are how the options are set:
[image]

Now after the first user has checked the document in, the second user who has Contribute permissions cannot see the revisions the first added when she simply clicks on the document and opens it Word. Now here's the kicker! If I have her first open the document by choosing the Open in Browser option, she can see the revisions. And while in the browser view she can choose to open in Word and she still sees the revisions when Word opens!

Comment: do you have content approval? also have u published the draft version?

Comment: What versions of Office are being used by the two users? This sounds like buggy behavior and may have been already fixed in a subsequent patch.

Comment: Waqas - content approval is not on. Thriggle - first thing I checked was their versions, the both are on the same version "Microsoft Word 2013 (15.0.4787.1000) MSO (15.0.4787.1002)".

Comment: Waqas - a major revision was published.

Answer (score 0):

From the last option select "NO" for 'require documents to be checked out before they can be edited'.

This will allow users updates to be view-able by others.